# Incorrect syntax here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT B.code + '-' + LEFT(F.code, 1) + '-' 
     + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AT.[description]  
                               ORDER BY ID) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [code] 
     + '-' + AST.CODE,
```

I tired with few options with () but nothing worked

```
SELECT B.code + '-' + LEFT(F.code, 1) + '-' 
       + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AT.[description] 
                                 ORDER BY ID) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [code] 
       + '-' + AST.CODE,
```

Comment: What didn't work about it? `AS [code] + '-' + AST.CODE` look wrong. You're aliasing the column and then trying to concatenate more values to it.

Comment: What does the *actual* query look like? What is the *actual* error message?

Comment: Once you format your code for readability it's easy to see what the error is. I'm sure the error message complained about that `AS` too

Answer (score 4):

You have placed "AS [code]" in a wrong place inside the string operation. Try this-

```
SELECT B.code + '-' + 
    LEFT(F.code, 1) + '-' + 
    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AT.[description] ORDER BY ID) AS VARCHAR(10)) + 
    '-' + AST.CODE AS [code]
```